# Microsoft_Azure_BotService Resource/BotSettings/BotSettingsBlade 41 BotSettingsBlade: Failed to fetch connection settings _errorData: undefined

Tags: azure, botframework

I have created a Bot Channel Registration on Azure the other day, but now I can't access the settings and channels. The browser console shows various error messages and the webpage only shows a blank page.

[image: This is how it shows on my Azure Dashboard]

[image: This is the console error]

I tried with another browser and clearing cache.

Comment: I'd like to know if other blades, such as Channels or Overview etc, could be accessed. Besides same issue appear with other bot service(s), or just this Bot Channel Registration?

Comment: Only the first four options are accesible. Settings shows some text on the corner. https://imgur.com/kjX7loc

Comment: DO you by chance have 3rd party cookies disabled?  We have seen this cause this behavior before

Answer (score 1):

What is your language and region set to in your Azure Portal settings?

I can see that it says "Es Seguro" instead of "Secure" so make sure your language is set to "English" and your region is set to "English (United States)" for example, and if the problem persist contact Azure Support.

Comment: The browser is in spanish, but Azure Portal is set to "English (United States)" https://imgur.com/WLQCTRM

Answer (score 0):

I found that Privacy Badger (from EFF) was interfering with Test the Bot and Channels.

"Disable Privacy Badger for this site"

For what its worth, my portal was set to English / English.